# How to handle TTF fonts with strange names with XeLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, truetype

I am trying to use this font http://www.dafont.com/ecran-monochrome.font?fpp=100, called "Écran Monochrome" in XeLaTeX.

As you can see it has a strange name, both because the accent and the space. XeLaTeX seems to be confused by this and it doesn't compile this document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Écran Monochrome}
\begin{document}
123
\end{document}
```

The question is **how do I specify this font in the document?** I tried many variants of this name, like removing the accent, the capitalization and the space (see below for current error messages.)

Gives the error:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Écran Monochrome" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

The TTF is well installed and usable from other applications (like LibreOffice in Linux.)

```
$ fc-list | grep cran
/home/user/.local/share/fonts/ecran-monochrome---monochrome-display.ttf: écran monochrome / monochrome display:style=Regular
```

Comment: Alternative solution: Use font file name instaed. Say, `\setmainfont{ecran-monochrome---monochrome-display.ttf}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Leo Liu's comment is actually a solution. We can use a file name of the font to load the font with the `fontspec` package. The similar problem is when a font is not actually installed or cannot be installed due to the user's limited rights on the computer and we still wish to use the font. We use `ExternalLocation` option for this purpose, I enclose an example where font was unzipped in the working directory and it hasn't been installed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ExternalLocation={./}]{ecran-monochrome---monochrome-display.ttf} % Écran Monochrome
\begin{document}
123
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: So, if the font is installed in user space (such as `~/.fonts` or `~/.local/share/fonts/`) then still XeLaTeX won't detect it? Where should it be detected? Do I have to tell XeLaTeX to update the database? After all was it a problem with the name of the font or the installation?

Comment: @alfC XeLaTeX is browsing common font directories, it shouldn't be a problem. It is updating font database regularly. Well, we could run `fc-cache -vf` on our own, if needed.

Comment: Ok, I tried that, the only way I can make it work is to put the full path (`ExternalLocation`) even if it well installed (in userspace, such as `~/.fonts`).

Comment: @alfC Hm, that is strange, both `~/.fonts` and `~/.local/share/fonts` are folders to be searched and they are a part of the font database.

Comment: @alfC Is the font's name `Écran Monochrome` or `écran monochrome`?

Comment: @cfr, I don't know, I tried both.