# How to write “Java” in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, java

How can I write "Java" in LaTeX so that the output looks as it is typeset on https://www.java.com/en/ (image below). For example `\textsc{Java}` doesn't look good. The image uses white text on red background, but it should just be normal black text.

[image: Java typeset]

Comment: If you find the correct font, it can be done in LaTeX, so I believe that you will find better answers on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ with the `typography` tag.

Comment: Discussion on finding the name of the font can be found elsewhere. For example here: http://fontslogo.com/java-logo-font/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not surprisingly, Sun Java logo uses [Sun Semibold](http://www.fonts.com/search/all-fonts?searchtext=sun%20semibold&submit=Search). As far as I can see it is not a free font. If you get it, you should get your result from `XeLaTeX` by doing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{sun_semibold.ttf}
\begin{document}
Java
\end{document}
```

The most I can do for you is to give you this bitmap produced by `www.fonts.com`, I expect you will get this with `XeLaTeX`:

[image: java]
[image: jred]

> Java©, the only language that had a marketing campaign budget.
>
> *Source: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c_family_interview.htm*

Comment: That seems great. According to http://fontslogo.com/java-logo-font/, then Quattrocento Sans Bold Font is the closely related free font. Could you show how to use the font for only a word when using pdflatex?

Comment: I think you can't with `pdflatex`, you have to use `xelatex` or `lualatex`. The simplest ways is to get your font in the same location as the document and use this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169688/how-to-handle-ttf-fonts-with-strange-names-with-xelatex. In my opion Quattrocento is not that similar.

Comment: Of course when it's used as a logo, there's nothing wrong with actually including it as a vector image.

Comment: @Christian, that's right and here it is http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Java_logo_and_wordmark.svg

Answer (score 14):

Quattrocento is possible, but different from sun:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{quattrocento,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\Huge\sffamily
\colorbox{red}{\color{white}\textbf{Java}}

\textbf{Java}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is even a package for Quattrocentro! Good to know. You don't need `fontenc` it seems.